# Why is there a difference in same DLL when adding from VS 2015 and VS 2017

Tags: .net, visual-studio

Why is there a difference in the DLL when I add a COM reference to my class library in Visual Studio 2015 and in Visual Studio 2017?

The reference is Microsoft `ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 Library`

How can I keep the DLL the same as in VS 2015 when I add it to VS 2017?

**VS 15**

```
Interop.ADODB.DLL size: 100K Ver 2.0.0.0
```

**VS 17**

```
Interop.ADODB.DLL size: 88K Ver 4.0.0.0
```

**The problem is this**
[image]

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "a difference in the DLL"? It would really help if you could add a [mcve], but *at least* clarify exactly what you mean.

Comment: Hmm, there is a lot you are not telling us.  The interop assembly has the wrong name.  On a properly configured dev machine, this COM reference is covered by a PIA, adodb.dll, stored in C:\Windows\assembly\GAC\ADODB\7.0.3300.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a.  Discovered with a registry key, HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Classes\TypeLib\{2A75196C-D9EB-4129-B803-931327F72D5C}\2.8, PrimaryInteropAssemblyName value.  If either is missing then the assembly has to be generated and the potential problems start.  Don't blindly copy this DLL, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Because .NET assemblies are in the GAC, when you have VS2017 it will automatically bind to the newer version of the dll.  This is generally done so that when important fixes are done in the platform, your app will get those benefits.  You can override the publisher's policy and not roll forward, but that isn't usually recommended.  This article should give the information you're looking for https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/redirect-assembly-versions

Comment: Ok, did another experiment. On Azure, I spun up a Win 10  VS 17 VM. I created just a simple class library that referenced the `Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 Library`. I set the target to `.Net FX 2.0` and `Interop.ADODB.dll` was a version 2 instead of version 4. This is different behavior from my `Windows 7 Pro VS 17` machine when I target the `.Net FX 2.0` and reference the same `COM` DLL, I get the version 4 DLL?